# JFreeChart - OHLC and a normal TimeSeries

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am starting with JfreeChart. I was able to create a OHLC chart. I want to add the average of Close on the same chart. I should be a TimeSeries ? Do you know how to do that, mixing the charts ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add the second dataset to the chart and set the renderer for the dataset:

```java
plot.setDataset(1, createAverageCloseDataset());
plot.setRenderer(1, new XYLineAndShapeRenderer());
```